# Top Level Members Leaderboard Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

So, i made few leaderboards command for many types of stuff, money leaderboard, quiz etc. but i have problem with leveling leaderboard, when i type command it gives me this error

```
(node:34294) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined
at Object.exports.run (/home/Lignjoslav/commands/generalno/leveltop.js:21:65)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

All leaderboards is made like this and i don't have problem with them, they work perfect but this one have this problem. Here is the command:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const db = require("quick.db");

exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {

    let komande = await db.fetch(`kanal_${message.guild.id}_komande`);
    if (message.channel.id !== komande && !message.member.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR"))
        return message.channel.send({
            embed: {
                title: `:video_game: Komande`,
                description: `Ovu komandu možeš koristiti samo u kanalu <#${komande}>`,
                color: 0x4CAAFF
            }
        });

    let levelTOP = await db
        .all()
        .filter(data => data.ID.startsWith(`level_${message.guild.id}`))
        .sort((a, b) => b.data - a.data);
    let content = "";

    for (let i = 0; i < levelTOP.length; i++) {
        if (i === 10) break;

        let user = client.users.cache.get(levelTOP[i].ID.split("_")[2]).username;

        content += `**${i + 1}.** __${user}__ - ${levelTOP[i].data} \n`;
    }

    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setDescription(`**__Tabela članova sa najviše levela__**\n\n${content}`)
        .setColor("#4CAAFF");

    message.channel.send(embed);
};
exports.help = {
    name: "leveltop",
    description: "lista članova sa najviše levela",
    usage: "leveltop",
    category: "generalno",
    listed: true
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`client.users.cache` is just a cache, it may or may not keep the entire data of the users connected to the bot. Instead try calling asynchronous [`client.users.fetch(id)`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/UserManager?scrollTo=fetch)

```js
const user = await client.users.fetch(levelTOP[i].ID.split("_")[2]);

content += `**${i + 1}.** __${user.username}__ - ${levelTOP[i].data} \n`;
```